# Varchar value split in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a column in a table

Table 1

```
Tid.   name   fid
-----------------
 1.    Abc.   233
 2.    def.   344
 3.    xyz.   455
```

Table 2

```
did.   Status.   name                   FID
-------------------------------------------
 1      Open.        Abu,def,xyz            233,344,455
```

Now I want to split these fid and name from table2 in a stored procedure like this:

```
ID   status   name   FID
---------------
 1.   Open.     Abc.   233
 2.    Open.    Def.   344
 3    Open.     xyz.   455
```

Update stored procedure

Query:

```
Create procedure as splitdata 
As 
Begin 
   Declare @fid varchar (500) 

   Select name, select item as fid 
   from spiltstring(@fid,',')) 
   from table1 
   Inner join table2 on table1.fid = table2.fid
```

This shows error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '233,344,455' to data type int

In table1 `fid` is `int` and in `table2` `fid` is `varchar` type.

Split string function is

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(1000))
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1

      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

How can I do this?

UPDATE

Ok according to @john solution I try this solution ...

But as I have multiple other tables

Like

```
Create procedure as sp2
    @tick int
As
    Select
        Table 4.column, Table 5.column, Table 3.column,
        --so here I used solution like this
        (Select b.fid 
         from table2 t2 
         cross apply 
             (Select fid = s2.retval 
              from [udf-str-parase] (t2.fid, ',') s2) b),
        Table 6.column
    From 
        Table 2
    Inner join 
        table4 on table4.id = table5.id
    ..........
    Where 
        tick = @tick
```

When I try to execute only cross apply query this shows perfect result

But when I try to execute whole stored procedure like this

```
Exec sp2 28
```

I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.this is not permitted. When the subquery follows =,!=,<=,>=,>,< or when the subquery iIs used an expression.

Any solutions?

Comment: Check.Update please

Answer (score 1):

The the help of a split/parse function and a CROSS APPLY

```
Declare @Table2 table (did int,Status varchar(50),name varchar(50),FID varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table2 values
(1,'Open.','Abu,def,xyz','233,344,455')


Select ID = Seq
      ,A.Status
      ,B.Name
      ,B.FID
 From  @Table2 A
 Cross Apply (
         Select Name=S1.RetVal
               ,FID =S2.RetVal
               ,Seq =S1.RetSeq
          From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Name,',') S1
          Join [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.FID,',')  S2
            on S1.RetSeq=S2.RetSeq
       ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  Status  Name    FID
1   Open.   Abu     233
2   Open.   def     344
3   Open.   xyz     455
```

The Split/Parse UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select @String as [*] For XML Path('')),@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Comment: This is too complicated

Comment: please check update question... I try ur solution and this shows an error

Comment: It's not too complicated @cooluser just because you don't understand